# JQuery - Unable to do a simple conditional test

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have a problem which is pretty simple I guess, but I cannot figure out how to fix it!

Here is my js code:

```
$('#attendees_nb_div').change(function() {
    if ($('#attendees_nb').val() < 1){
        $('#attendees_nb').val(1);
    }
    $('.reservation_time_cell_div').each(function() {
        var array = this.id.split(':');
        if (array[4] < $('#attendees_nb').val()) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            console.log('Value of array[4]: ', array[4]);
            console.log('Value of $(\'#attendees_nb\').val(): ', $('#attendees_nb').val());
            console.log('Test result array[4] < $(\'#attendees_nb\').val(): ', array[4] < $('#attendees_nb').val());
        }
    });
});
```

Here is the output of the console:

```
Value of array[4]:  15
Value of $('#attendees_nb').val():  2
Test result array[4] < $('#attendees_nb').val():  true
```

Why is 15 < 2 True?
I noticed as well that I have true results for:
350 < 4, 35 < 4, 50 < 6, 60 < 7...
So I guess it is testing against the first digit only of array[4], but why?
How to test against all digits?

Comment: i would be probably a char array! parsing it to int would fix!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert `array[4]` and `$('#attendees_nb').val()` into integer like following

```
    if (parseInt(array[4]) < parseInt($('#attendees_nb').val())) {
```

This will help you.

Comment: That's it... Thanks a lot. I am a beginner, spent hours to figure out :/

Answer (score 1):

Add `parseInt()` around the values you check.

Answer (score 1):

What you are doing is compare a string with an integer.The result of `val()` is always a string.To compare it with an integer you have to turn it to an integer
using `parseInt()` which takes a string as an argument and return it as an integer. So here you are:

```
$('#attendees_nb_div').change(function() {
    //Store it to speed up things a little bit
    var valueToCheck = parseInt(($('#attendees_nb').val());
    if ($valueToCheck < 1){
        $('#attendees_nb').val(1);
    }
    $('.reservation_time_cell_div').each(function() {
        var array = this.id.split(':');
        if (array[4] < valueToCheck) {
            $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
            console.log('Value of array[4]: ', array[4]);
            console.log('Value of $(\'#attendees_nb\').val(): ', valueToCheck);
            console.log('Test result array[4] < $(\'#attendees_nb\').val(): ', array[4] < valueToCheck);
        }
    });
});
```

From MDN:

> The **parseInt()** function parses a string argument and returns an integer of the specified radix (the base in mathematical numeral systems).

More details about [parseInt](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)